# Why didn't the Ori attack earth in "The Ark of Truth"?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

When the Ori had 7 ships above earth they just stood there until the other story-lines wrapped up, as well as the entire time it took to take the Ark from one galaxy to another.  Why would they do that?

Comment: Because of the mighty power of the plot :-P

Comment: Hallowed *are* the Ori. The flames of ignorance burn without pain. Beware the power or it will consume you before you know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Landry offers a few different guesses in his chat with the Prior. You can take your pick which you think is most likely, but to my mind **the fact that the Prior mentions Earth's defences** suggest that it's the topmost.

- The Priors of the Ori are overly cautious. Earth has shown itself to have [formidable planetary defences](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bXuaCaLmtX8) in the recent past. The Ori would be especially wary of those since they're based on Lantean design.
- The Priors of the Ori may simply be delaying until they have *overwhelming* forces in place.
- The Priors may be experiencing an existential crisis. Their gods have just died and this may be causing them some level of anxiety and hesitation.
- Earth is the juiciest plum in the whole Galaxy. Their goal may be to simply *threaten* destruction from the sky in the hopes that its people will see sense.

> **LANDRY:** *Sure, you've tried to warn us a couple of times, but come on, you can do better than that, can't you? We've been a tremendous
>   pain in your proverbial backside. You don't really expect me to
>   believe that you—you've just been saving the best for last, do you?
>   What's wrong? You guys are never speechless! I'll tell you what I
>   think. I say this move reeks of desperation. You're not all that sure
>   it's a slam-dunk.*
>
> **PRIOR:** *Your defenses are no match for the might of the Ori, which shall rain down apocalypse upon—*
>
> **LANDRY:** *Right, right. Now here's a news-flash, the Ori are dead. We killed them. Sent a weapon devised by an ex-Ancient through the
>   Supergate and wiped them all out [beat] These beings you call gods,
>   the ones who lied to you, manipulated you, for their own selfish,
>   power-hungry reasons, are gone, and everything you think you're doing
>   in their name is entirely without meaning.*